# Return default value if condition can not be satisfied

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML like that :

```
<div id="MyArea">
    <div class="data-content">The content is not satisfied </div>
    <div class="data-content">[value] </div>
    <div class="data-content">[valueme] </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want run a `Function` in each class (`data-content`) that have brackets. Others class (have no brackets), keep default and do not change anything. I use script below, but it is be error.

```
$("#MyArea .data-content").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html(),
        values = content.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);

    if (value !== "") {
        $(this).closest(".data-content").myFunc({
            //Run myFunc in this .data-content if values has brackets.
        }
        else { 
            //return the default value and do not change the content inside of that class if it has no brackets. How can I do that?}
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: And what's your problem, apart from syntax errors?  What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @FelixKling: The function does not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here given the numerous syntax problems, but you can use `test` in the condition to see if the regex matches anything. Also, you cannot `return` anything from each iteration in a `$.each` loop, so that is redundant.

Try this:

```
$("#MyArea .data-content").each(function () {
    var content = $(this).html();
    if (/[^[\]]+(?=])/g.test(content)) {
        $(this).closest(".data-content").css('color', '#C00');
    };
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/CVbex/1/)

In place of `.css()` in my example you could call your function.

Comment: Ok. It is exact solution i want. Thank for your help.